# adMob test ads not working on phone but does work on tablet

Tags: android, admob

I have been testing adMob and it was working fine in the emulator, on my phone and on my tablet.

Now, without making any changes to the app, test ads are no longer working on my phone, but are still working on my tablet and in the emulator.

As I have not changed the code of my app, I just don't know where to look.

I am getting this error on my phone

```
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ads may run on the device but not with natural efficiency. Make sure the ad appears in the display on the emulator and change the default code with the code for your advertisement on Adobe. The display will be better when the application is launched for users.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the problem today, albeit inadvertently.

I turned my phone on and off to try to resolve a problem with the Samsung keyboard, and when I went back in to my app it instantly showed ads!!!

So something in the phone was obviously fubar, which a cold boot solved, and I have zero idea what it was lol.